# Compile a .dll file of dlib

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll, dlib

I want to import a script that uses Dlib. Problem is that it won't compile without .dll file of Dlib.

Is there any way to get it into my project?

I have .lib file but I don't think there is a way to convert that to .dll.

Comment: I don't have any compiled .dll file only .lib and .obj

Comment: I have complied the dlib file with the .dll extension but unity refuses to load it.
I have used this line to import the function of dll into unity and placed the dll in Plugin folder `internal static class OpenCVInterop
{
 [DllImport("tracking_dll")]
 internal static extern int Init(ref int outCameraWidth, ref int outCameraHeight);

 [DllImport("tracking_dll")]
 internal static extern int Close();
 }
`

Comment: No i changed the settings in properties Sheet for the dilb project (which i obtained from cmake made build folder)...to .dll instead of .lib but even with the produced .dll file I didn't had any luck

Comment: @sakshamsharma could you share how you complied dlib source into a .dll file? I'd like to use the .dll in a C# WPF project.

Answer (score 0):

@ali I made a make file of the dlib file using c-make and then used visual basic to compile it but in export setting I changed the. Exe to. Dll